# Elasticsearch 6: Failed to parse date with milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm generating the date via php using the [Chronos](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos) library. It's using the [formatting syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) php uses. Elasticsearch is version 6.2.4. To connect with the ES server I'm using [Elastica](https://elastica.io/). I keep getting this error:

> failed to parse [created]

when sending this date:

```
// 2019-08-14 08:40:05.887179
Chronos::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.v');
```

This is my mapping

```
"created": {
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    "type": "date"
},
```

In the log of the ES server I see this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:207

If I change the date format to

```
// 2019-08-14 08:40:05.887179
Chronos::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-08-14 08:45:35.809896" is malformed at "896"

So how can I get the milliseconds right? :( I don't mind the format as long as I can store the milliseconds somehow.

Comment: Have you tried to change your date format to `"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"` ? Your date seems to have microseconds precision, 2019-08-14 08:45:35.809896, where 809 is your miliseconds and 896 is microseconds.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!